# Two process communicate in two computers by Erlang

Tags: linux, erlang, multiprocessing

This is a 2-process communication program in Erlang.

I need to run each process in a different computer.

I need to run 
     erl -name ping

in computer2, whose host name is linux-2.mydomain

And , I need to run

```
 erl -name pong
```

in computer1, whose host name is linux-1.mydomain

Then,

On computer 1, I run:

```
  tut17:start_pong().
```

On computer 2, I run:

```
 tut17:start_ping(pong@linux-1)
```

But, I got error:

- exception error: bad argument in an arithmetic expression
   in operator  -/2
      called as pong@linux - 1

it seems that Erlang thought that the " - " is minus operator in "linux-1".

So, how to make Erlang understand my command ?

Any help is really appreciated.

The code is below:

```
 -module(tut17).

 -export([start_ping/1, start_pong/0,  ping/2, pong/0]).

 ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
     {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished,
     io:format("ping finished~n", []);

 ping(N, Pong_Node) ->
     {pong, Pong_Node} ! {ping, self()},
    receive
        pong ->
             io:format("Ping received pong~n", [])
    end,
 ping(N - 1, Pong_Node).

 pong() ->
     receive
         finished ->
              io:format("Pong finished~n", []);

         {ping, Ping_PID} ->
               io:format("Pong received ping~n", []),

               Ping_PID ! pong,
           pong()
  end.

  start_pong() ->
       register(pong, spawn(tut17, pong, [])).

  start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
       spawn(tut17, ping, [3, Pong_Node]).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the node name in single quotes:

```
tut17:start_ping('pong@linux-1')
```

http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66276

> An atom should be enclosed
>   in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or
>   if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters,
>   underscore (_), or @.